# Как построить контур по координатам вершин фигуры, состоящей из квадратов?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, геометрия

Есть двумерный массив в котором хранится фигура, состоящая из квадратов (каждый элемент - квадрат). Не могу придумать алгоритм, который будет преобразовывать этот массив в массив вершин этой фигуры (каждая вершина должна иметь координаты x и y), которые находятся в таком порядке, что переходя от одной вершины к следующей в массиве, получается эта фигура.

Язык реализации не особо важен (но желательно js), хочется просто понять алгоритм.

---

[image: Изначальный массив]

[image: То, что должно получиться]

Comment: Разбейте набор синих клеток на компоненты связности. В каждой компоненте отыщите левый нижний квадрат. Его левый нижний угол на границе. Из угла выходит ровно два ребра, которые разделяют синий и белый квадраты. По одному ребру перейдите к соседу, снова найдите разделяющее ребро, перейдите к соседу... Повторяйте пока не придете в исходный угол.

Comment: Отыщите все вершины у которых есть и синие и белые квадраты-соседи. Из неупорядоченного набора вершин вытягивайте цепочки вершин-соседей. Этот способ кажется проще, но есть подводные камни.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнить массив где хранится фигура периметром из нолей. Затем последовательно квадратом 2х2 (с шагом в одну строку, столбец) просканировать весь дополненный массив на условие нахождения вершины фигуры в центре квадрата (вершина попадает в квадрат, если есть один угол 0 и остальные 1 или один угол 1 и остальные 0) и зафиксировать координаты вершин.